# tripsta luggage allowance

Tags: luggage, sas

I am considering to book a few flight tickets with tripsta, since they have clearly the best offer for the date and route I've been looking for. I am however not able to find out if the ticket price includes a piece of checked baggage or if this has to be booked extra.

In their FAQ's, tripsta is simply referring to the airline when it comes to '[how much baggage is included](http://www.tripsta.co.uk/faqs/Flights#q3292)?'.

The tickets are for class 'economy (O)' on an SAS flight. Since SAS has replaced the boring economy class with more fancy product names like 'SAS Go Light', 'SAS Go' and 'SAS Plus', consulting the airline's [web site for baggage rules](http://www.flysas.com/en/uk/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage/) does not help any further.

Contacting SAS on the phone, I only got the reply that they can only confirm the exact conditions if I book my tickets through their web site. If I book through an agent, I have to contact the agent for the conditions of their tickets. That's fair enough.

Trying to get tripsta customer service to answer the phone seems fruitless. At least I gave up after waiting for quite some time.

Is there any other location or resource, where I can confirm if checked baggage is included in an economy (O) ticket for an SAS flight from Norway to Germany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Per [SAS earning chart](https://www.flysas.com/en/eurobonus/point-charts/sas-points-charts/#tab4) O is Go and not something higher.
2. Whether it's Go or Go light, per this [flyertalk post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/25391364-post66.html) can't be decided based on the booking class alone:

> SAS Go Light will be available in the same booking classes as SAS Go, but will be offered to a lower fare than SAS Go and exclude checked baggage allowance in the ticket.
>
> It will be possible to buy checked baggage, as well as other additional services, from time of reservation until departure. For passengers who want to travel with checked baggage, it will be more favorable to buy a SAS Go ticket with baggage included.

3. The very recent [announcement for Go Light](http://www.sasgroup.net/en/sas-go-light-for-those-who-travel-light/) says

> The concept is set to be rolled out on 8 September [2015], initially as a test on routes between Scandinavia and six European countries – Finland, France, Greece, the Republic of Ireland, the Netherlands and Spain.

Notably Germany is missing. I would conclude that you will be booked into SAS Go as Go Light doesn't exist on this route at this time.

4. If your OTA doesn't display clearly what are you paying for then stay clear! By the time you get to the payment screen it should be clear whether you are getting any meals and what baggage allowance you have.

Comment: Booking the same flight directly from SAS, 'SAS Go' is indeed the cheapest offer and in that fare, a checked piece of baggage is included. If you look at the price list for excess baggage (e.g. later adding checked baggage to a 'SAS Go Light' ticket), there is also no option or tariff for adding baggage to a 'SAS Go Light' fare for flights to Germany. Booking somewhere else is not only a question of money, but that on the return flight, tickets seem only to be available from tripsta. Booking directly from SAS, there are no tickets available on the flight.

Comment: "no option or tariff for adding baggage to a 'SAS Go Light' fare for flights to Germany" because there are no SAS Go Light fares to Germany, that's why. Also, I suspect by the time you get to payment tripsta won't have tickets either. Many OTAs play this bait and switch trick (or perhaps it's just inaptitude and not malevolence but it's certainly irritating).

Comment: I got an e-mail response from tripsta today confirming that luggage is included in the offered fare, so I dared to take a chance. The tickets were offered by tripsta for 105€ and I was able to book three tickets without any problems. While the flight can be booked also directly from SAS at the moment, the price is currently 895€ for the cheapest 'SAS Go' category.

Comment: Sometimes you get lucky. I'd check on the SAS website whether you are really ticketed now and in a few days as well just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, the ticket number can be found on the SAS web page and is shown as 'confirmed'. Strangely, tripsta is still selling tickets for the same price.